# sort two arrays in O(n) (time and space)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, computer-science

> Given two (possibly unsorted) arrays, `A` and `B` and the operation `swap(A, B, i)` which swaps the elements `A[i]` and `B[i]`, you need to return the minimal number of swaps so the two arrays are strictly increasing (or `-1` if impossible)

I came up pretty fast with a greedy solution (I can attach the code if you want) but apparently it doesn't yield the correct answer in some cases (which I'm unaware of).

Why is the greedy approach not good enough? 
What could be an alternative approach to reach the minimum number of swaps?

**EDIT:**
Here's my code

```
def solution(A, B):
    n = len(A)
    swaps = 0
    for i in range(1, n):

        if A[i] > A[i - 1] and B[i] > B[i - 1]:
            continue

        if A[i] < A[i - 1] and B[i] < B[i - 1]:
            return -1
        elif A[i] < A[i - 1]:
            if B[i - 1] < A[i]:
                A[i], B[i] = B[i], A[i]
                swaps += 1
            else:
                return -1
        else:
            # B[i] < B[i - 1]
            if A[i - 1] < B[i]:
                A[i], B[i] = B[i], A[i]
                swaps += 1
            else:
                return -1


    return swaps

# test
assert(solution([5, 3, 7, 7, 10], [1, 6, 6, 9, 9]))
```

Comment: "Why is the greedy approach not good enough?" how can we know without knowing what greedy approach you used

Comment: add the code that you tried

Comment: @juvian, you're right. Let me attach the code

Comment: @Elimination are you posting this in an online site? Do you know that A and B always have the same length?

Comment: @juvian, Yes, sorry for not mentioning it out. A and B have the same length

Comment: There are several < that I would change for <=

Comment: but it suppose to be strictly increasing, @juvian

Comment: Thats why, you have conflicts when its < or its equal, all your conflicts are just checked with <

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DP to achieve this:

One approach can be:
For each pair of A[i] and B[i], we can choose to swap or not. So we define two dp arrays, keep[i] means if we don't swap A[i] and B[i], what's the min number of swaps. swap[i] is the min number of swaps if we swap A[i] and B[i].

- A[i] > A[i -1] && B[i] > B[i - 1],
  if we choose to keep, we should keep the previous i - 1 elements. So keep[i] = keep[i - 1]
  If we choose to swap, in order to maintain the sequencing order, we must swap the previous i - 1 th element. So swap[i] = swap[i - 1] + 1;
- A[i] > B[i - 1] && B[i] > A[i - 1]
  If we choose to keep, keep[i] = Math.min(keep[i], swap[i - 1])
  If we choose to swap, swap[i] = Math.min(swap[i], keep[i - 1] + 1)
- For case such as A[i] < B[i - 1], return -1

Time complexity : O(n)

Comment: thank you so much (I had DP in the back of my mind for a moment but I gave up on that). I'll try to work it from here!

Comment: Isn't it a bit more complicated than that? when you're looking at the (i-1)th place it may be swapped so you need to consider both cases accordingly.

Comment: @Elimination it covers most of the edge cases, and you can add more to it as you proceed. And you have to be careful when maintaining your arrays and make sure you implement all the cases properly.

Comment: last question please, I'm referring to case 2: let's suppose we wish to keep the i-th elements as they are. Isn't it just `keep[i] = swap[i - 1]`. I don't understand the `Math.min()` use.

Comment: to demonstrate this case we can look at `A=[3, 10], B=[5, 4]`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Elimination min is required in case 2 as in case 2  exactly one of these columns swapped. So that is why we need min in this case.

Comment: but you're defining `keep[i]` and `swap[i]` (in case 2) with itself. Should it have some initial value? I'm still confused